# GobblinCli is not getting loaded while running cli commands

Tags: gobblin

I am trying to set up a gobblin in my mac. when I am running **cli run** getting below error.
Do we need to set up or configure anything before running gobblin cli commands?

```
$ bin/gobblin.sh cli run
ls: apache-gobblin-incubating-sources-0.14.0/bin/../lib: No such file or directory
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.gobblin.runtime.cli.GobblinCli
```

Any help appreciated !!!

Answer (score 2):

Are you running this from the source repo directly? Try the following steps:

### Step 1: Build the distro (skipping unnecessary tasks)

```
# From the root folder
./gradlew :gobblin-distribution:assemble -x javadoc -x test -x findbugsMain -x checkstyleMain -x rat
```

This should give you the distribution tarball under
**build/gobblin-distribution/distributions/**

```
ls build/gobblin-distribution/distributions/
apache-gobblin-incubating-bin-0.15.0.tar.gz     apache-gobblin-incubating-bin-0.15.0.tar.gz.sha512
```

### Step 2: Copy distro to a clean area and unzip it

```
# from the source repo root
mkdir <my-gobblin-work-directory>
cd <my-gobblin-work-directory>
tar -xzf ../build/gobblin-distribution/distributions/apache-gobblin-incubating-bin-0.15.0.tar.gz
```

This should give you a **gobblin-dist** folder

### Step 3: Run the cli command

```
./gobblin-dist/bin/gobblin cli run
```